# How can I make an editor which is similar to Outlook editor?

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm developing a tool to manage email lists, send and receive emails like outlook.

I'm stuck at the editor (compose area) part.
I tried to use Rich textbox and got 2 problem.

1. Rich Textbox doesn't allow me to paste pictures from the sources (web-page or docx)
2. I have no idea how to convert the content in the rich textbox into HTML format to send it out.

Any ideas? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not free, but you can check out the DevExpress tool suite. They have Rich Text Editor that mimics much of Word's functionality. You did not mention what you are building this tool in, but this can be for ASP.NET/MVC as well as WinForms/WPF.

https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxRichEditDemos/Default.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BTW, I just found this article regarding my question. https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=8

Answer (score 0):

Outlook itself uses Word (well, Word-light) for message editing.

Comment: Thank you for answering but how can I paste picture into rich textbox and convert the content to HTML format?

Comment: @ Tony Hinkle - it does: the suggestion is to automate Word to edit Outlook messages.